# JS Object changed during res.send

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm having some troubles with Express for sending an object in a RESTful API. This should be very simple, but I'm having a weird bug.
Here is my code:

```
result = result.map(function (elem) {
  elem.progress = elem.progress.map(prog => prog.progress).reduce((x, y)  => x + y, 0);
  return ({'user': elem});
});
result.forEach((elem) => console.log('#', elem.user.progress));
console.log('result:', result);
res.send(result);
```

This is the data I use to test it:

```
[
  {
    "user": {
      "user_id": 1,
      "id": 354,
      "already_connected": 1,
      "progress": [
        {
          "id": 520,
          "teams_user_id": 354,
          "a_category_id": 1,
          "progress": 100,
          "created": "2016-11-10T13:44:30.000Z",
          "modified": "2016-11-10T13:44:33.000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 521,
          "teams_user_id": 354,
          "a_category_id": 2,
          "progress": 100,
          "created": "2016-11-10T13:44:33.000Z",
          "modified": "2016-11-10T13:44:35.000Z"
        },
      ],
      "user": {
        "name": "Foo bar",
        "avatar_id": 6673,
        "default_avatar_int": 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I expect progress to be equal to 200, which is the case when I do a console.log before res.send, but when I receive the data in Postman, progress is still equal to an array. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the data you use work initially then you probably forgot to navigate to `.user` property. Check this:

```js
var result = [
  {
    "user": {
      "user_id": 1,
      "id": 354,
      "already_connected": 1,
      "progress": [
        {
          "id": 520,
          "teams_user_id": 354,
          "a_category_id": 1,
          "progress": 100,
          "created": "2016-11-10T13:44:30.000Z",
          "modified": "2016-11-10T13:44:33.000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 521,
          "teams_user_id": 354,
          "a_category_id": 2,
          "progress": 100,
          "created": "2016-11-10T13:44:33.000Z",
          "modified": "2016-11-10T13:44:35.000Z"
        },
      ],
      "user": {
        "name": "Foo bar",
        "avatar_id": 6673,
        "default_avatar_int": 1
      }
    }
  }
]

result = result.map(function (elem) {
  // you forgot to navigate to `.user` property
  elem.progress = elem.user.progress.map(prog => prog.progress).reduce((x, y)  => x + y, 0);
  return ({'user': elem});
});
result.forEach((elem) => console.log('#', elem.user.progress));
console.log('result:', result);
```

Comment: No sorry, this is the data after ({'user': elem});

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data before you try to process it?

Comment: Solved the bug by adding elem = elem.toJSON(); at the start of the first result.map